Get the datetime range between two dates
I have implemented below code to get date range -
from datetime import timedelta, date,datetime

def daterange(date1, date2):
    # Iterate over the range of days between date1 and date2
    for n in range(int((date2 - date1).days) + 1):
        # Yield each date within the range
        yield date1 + timedelta(n)

##Logic to fetch data in daterange
current_date = datetime.today()
# day = int(current_date.strftime('%d'))
day = 19
year = int(current_date.strftime('%Y'))
month = int(current_date.strftime('%m'))

if str(day) == '19':
    # Define the start date
    start_dt = date(year, month, 18)
    # Define the end date
    end_dt = date(year, month, day)
elif str(day) == '28' or str(day) == '30' or str(day) == '31' or str(day) == '29':
    # Define the start date
    start_dt = date(year, month, 16)
    # Define the end date
    end_dt = date(year, month, day)

# Iterate over the range of dates generated by the daterange function
for dt in daterange(start_dt, end_dt):
    # date in the format YYYY-MM-DD
    dated = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    startdate = str(dated) + 'T00:00:00Z'
    enddate = str(dated) + 'T03:00:00Z'
    print(startdate)
    print(enddate)

It gives below output -
2024-06-18
2024-06-18T00:00:00Z
2024-06-18T03:00:00Z
2024-06-19
2024-06-19T00:00:00Z
2024-06-19T03:00:00Z

I want to return this date range in interval of two hours for each day-
Expected output -
2024-06-18T00:00:00Z
2024-06-18T02:00:00Z
2024-06-18T02:00:00Z
2024-06-18T04:00:00Z
2024-06-18T04:00:00Z
2024-06-18T06:00:00Z
2024-06-18T06:00:00Z
2024-06-18T08:00:00Z......
2024-06-18T22:00:00Z
2024-06-19T00:00:00Z......
2024-06-19T00:00:00Z
2024-06-19T02:00:00Z....

Any help would be appreciated.

What is supposed to happen if the current day is none of 19, 28, 29, 30 or 31?

No actions, can we focus on the logic to get the daterange in interval of 2 hours?

You can use the pandas function pd.date_range() with which you can specify the frequency, like this:
pd.date_range("2024-06-18 00:00", "2024-06-19 02:00", freq="2h")

This returns a DatetimeIndex object that contains dates in Timestamp objects, but if you need to, you can use to_pydatetime() method to get the dates in datetime objects
pd.date_range("2024-06-18 00:00", "2024-06-19 02:00", freq="2h").to_pydatetime()


can I create list of lists for all the values , like for all 18th datetime range in a list and 19th datetime in a another list and both of these lists in a single list ?

Just use list(pd.date_range("2024-06-18 00:00", "2024-06-19 02:00", freq="2h")) to get all dates in a list. If you need the list to iterate in a loop you can use the DatetimeIndex object directly

I think this is what you're looking for:
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def dates(start, end):
    def normalise(d):
        return datetime(d.year, d.month, d.day)
    _start = normalise(start)
    _end = normalise(end)
    while _start < _end:
        yield _start
        _start += timedelta(hours=2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    today = datetime.today()
    for d in dates(today, today+timedelta(days=1)):
        print(d.isoformat()+"Z")

This starts from the current day ignoring the time component and continues producing datetime objects at 2hr intervals.
e.g.,
2024-06-19T00:00:00Z
2024-06-19T02:00:00Z
2024-06-19T04:00:00Z
2024-06-19T06:00:00Z
2024-06-19T08:00:00Z
2024-06-19T10:00:00Z
2024-06-19T12:00:00Z
2024-06-19T14:00:00Z
2024-06-19T16:00:00Z
2024-06-19T18:00:00Z
2024-06-19T20:00:00Z
2024-06-19T22:00:00Z

